# SQL join ON not equal in Mysql

Tags: mysql

I have two tables. Both contains question id field. I want to get all records from first table that are not present in second one. I don't want to use "NOT IN" constrain as second table having more than 400000 records.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Try something like

```
SELECt  t1.*
FROM    Table1 t1 LEFT JOIN
        Table2 t2   ON  t1.questionID = t2.questionID
WHERE   t2.questionID IS NULL
```

Answer (score 5):

Typically you would do this using a `LEFT JOIN` combined with a `WHERE` clause selecting every row where the joined table returns no results.

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM   Table1 t1
       LEFT OUTER JOIN Table2 t2 ON t2.ID = t1.ID
WHERE  t2.ID IS NULL
```

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
select from t1
right join t2 on t2.id = t1.id where t2.id is null
```