# How to write "where" clause in hive to filter out values in another table

Tags: hive

I have a table "mytable" contains several columns including one called "ip." There is another table called "bots" with only one column "bot", which is a list of several ip address values. I want to filter out all rows in mytable with "ip" value in table bots.

I wrote

```
select * from mytable
where ip not in (select bot from bots);
```

Apparently this is not the way to do it. I am wondering what is the correct syntax.

I googled around but the keywords here "where" and "in" are too common in the English language and hence hard to find any useful results.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5040663/sql-join-on-not-equal-in-mysql this may be your answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select mytable.* from
mytable left outer join bots on mytable.id = bots.bot
where bots.bot is null
```